# Jquery is not loading before backbone even after configuring require using shim value. Please tell me what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am new to Backbone and require js.
Please review my init.js for any bugs if any as it's not working.
Also please suggest any other approach for the same purpose.
And i am running this on my localhost.

Here is my init.js file that i am calling as data-main from index.html.

```
requirejs.config({
    waitSeconds: 200,
    paths:{
        'jquery':'./jquery',
        'backbone':'./backbone',
        'underscore':'./underscore'
    },
    shim:{
        'backbone': {
            dep: ['underscore,jquery']
        },       
        'bootstrap':{
            dep: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});

require([
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "handlebars",
    "bootstrap",
    "text"
], function ($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, Bootstrap, text) {

});

require(["../routes/router"], function () {
    Backbone.history.start();
    console.log('history started');
});
```

ExactError can be seen in this image [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OUDd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Backbone has not needed a `shim` in a while. So you should remove it. Also, the field you should use is `deps`, not `dep`. So your final `shim` should be:

```
shim:{
    'bootstrap':{
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
```

Comment: Without the shim how do we configure the loading order..?

Comment: Like any other AMD module: Backbone now calls `define`, which lists the dependencies. (You can find old answers on SO that suggest using a shim because earlier versions did not call `define`.)

Comment: After correcting 'dep'  to 'deps' and " 'underscore,jquery' " to " 'underscore','jquery' " , It works fine.  So thanks a lot  :) Although it's not working if i remove backbone from shim. And  can you explain how backbone call's define because 'define' is nowhere inside backbone.js. ...

Comment: Look at the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) and search for `define(`. It is very near the top.

Comment: When i use this... then i am getting a error 
"type uncaught error :backbone.js:382 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined " ..